# A conditional JOIN depending on whether the foreign key is NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have a table PEOPLE where a person may belong to an Organisation (in table ORGs). If they don't, then the orgID field is NULL. If they do, well there is a match with an ORGs.OrgID row.

How do I create what I think is a condition join? In other words, if PEOPLE.orgID is NULL then return "None", but if the PEOPLE.orgID is not NULL, then return the corresponding ORGs.Name

```
|------------|      |------------|
|PEOPLE      |      |ORGs        |
|------------|      |------------|
|personID    |      |OrgID       |
|orgID       |      |Name        |
|Name        |      |            |
|------------|      |------------|
```

Comment: Check link for IFNULL, ISNULL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **LEFT OUTER JOIN** with **IFNULL()**

Try this:

```
SELECT P.personID, P.Name, IFNULL(O.Name, 'None') OrgName
FROM PEOPLE P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORGs O ON P.orgID = O.OrgID
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `left outer join` with `coalesce()`:

```
select p.*, coalesce(o.name, 'None') as orgname
from people p left join
     orgs o
     on p.orgID = o.orgid;
```